# How do I call a function whenever the timing of the video that is playing is a Map key

Tags: javascript, react-native, video

as an exemple, i want to do a vibration when video reach 7 seconds. But i need it to vibrate at the exactly second/milliseconds.

I already tried to:
Set progressUpdateInterval to 1 millisecond but the video stops working correctly.

The Video Component:

```
 <Video
    onEnd={onEnd}
    onLoad={onLoad}
    onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
    posterResizeMode={'cover'}
    onProgress={onProgress}
    progressUpdateInterval={1}
    paused={paused}
    ref={(ref) => (videoPlayer.current = ref)}
    source={external ? { uri: videoURL } : videoURL}
    resizeMode={"contain"}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
  >
  </Video>
```

And the OnProgress function:

```
const onProgress = (data) => {
if (!isLoading) {
  //var timeSeconds = Math.trunc(data.currentTime);
  setCurrentTime(data.currentTime);
  const hapticMap = new Map();
  hapticMap.set(hapticSet);
    
  if (hapticMap.has(data.currentTime)) {
  
      Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Heavy);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try with a small value like 10 or 100 as progressUpdateInterval ? (There is a strange thing in the docs https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#onprogress they talk about seconds where on the progressUpdateInterval its milisecs...)

Comment: i tried 50 as progressUpdateInterval and it worked fine, but with 50 millisecs i still need a way to sync it, since i cant verify every millisec and it doenst calls exactly 50-50-50 interval